# How do I get the link text using Beautiful Soup for each item in my scraper?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a scraper for Yellow Pages and I am trying to figure out how to get the website for each listing in search results included in the CSV output. The Website is listed right next to each listing.

I am using beautiful soup 4 on Python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import requests
import csv
import httplib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Nashville%2C+TN"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

yellowpages_list=[]

for item in g_data:
    business_name = item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text
    try:
        street_address = item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        locality = item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})[0].text.replace(',','')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        region = item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "addressRegion"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        postalcode = item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        primary = item.contents[1].find_all("li", {"class": "primary"})[0].text
    except:
        pass

    business=[business_name,street_address,locality,region,postalcode]
    yellowpages_list.append(business)

with open ('filename.csv','wb') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    for row in yellowpages_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like YellowPages is using `class="track-visit-website"` on their visit-website links.

Try this:

```
try:
    url = item.find("a", {"class": "track-visit-website"})["href"]
except:
    pass
```

P.S. You don't need to use `find_all()` and then get the first element of the array. `find()` will do the same thing for you.